# Toolbar becomes empty on Oreo devices, but same code works on Nougat and lower versions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-8.0-oreo

I am facing an issue on Oreo OS for an existing application. The toolbar becomes empty for same code on Oreo whereas it works on Nougat and lower versions.

The following images show the state when the app is launched. We can see that the toolbar is visible and has the required text.

[Marshmallow First Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zzPt.png)

[Oreo First Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rWaG.png)

Whereas when we try to change the fragment by some button click or navigation drawer, we see that the toolbar data is empty and the hamburger icon is missing.

[Marshmallow Fragment Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kpQx.png)

[Oreo Fragment Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUXdz.png)

I am sure this code is not a good way of writing code and uses a lot of incorrect code or issues with work. But this code has been passed through hands of multiple teams and hence the bad quality. We are trying to improve the code.

Please find the code attached below for reference.

Toolbar Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolBar_leftIconsLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolBar_titleTextView"
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolBar_leftIconsLinearLayout"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolBar_leftIconsLinearLayout"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolBar_rightIconsLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Base Activity:

```
public void setupActionBar(boolean backEnabled, String title) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        if (backEnabled) {
            addLeftIcon(R.drawable.back, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onHomePressed();
                }
            });
        }

        if (title != null && !title.isEmpty()) {
            changeToolbarText(title);
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Main Activity does not have any action bar or toolbar code. The fragments include the layout for it.

The `onActivityCreated` method in the `Fragment` has the following code for setting up the Action Bar.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setupActionBar(false, getString(R.string.myOrdersFragment_toolbarTitle));

    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).addLeftIcon(R.drawable.menu, mLeftToolbarIconListener);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).enableSwipeToRefresh(true);
}
```

Please let me know what am I missing here. My assumption here is that maybe Android has upgraded some stuff with Fragments which might not support Toolbar change or Support Action Bar is changed; maybe the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` won't work if the action bar is already set.